# Play Rmvb On ubuntu Saucy 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I have used to play RMVB on totem at ubuntu quantal and raring after updating to saucy and installing restricted extras  it give message about additional plug-in needed and it play only sound.
any idea ??

Comment: after installing ubuntu restricted extras and playin through totem player it search for plugin and it shows this meessage :The playback of this movie requires a RealVideo 4.0 decoder plugin which is not installed, and it play only sound

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You can always edit your own question. If will make it easier on people who may respond if you move your comment into your question.

Comment: Have you tried VLC or mplayer?

Comment: VLC & mplayer works fine

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 2):

Just install " VLC player " From " Ubuntu Software Center "
then right click on the .rmvb file > open with > " VLC player "