# How can I play a rmvb file in ubuntu trusty?

Tags: 14.04, video, file-format

I have an video file in rmvb format, but vlc player and totem crashes when I try to play it. Is there any way to install realplayer on ubuntu, and if not, how is it possible to play this video on ubuntu?

p.s.: sorry, my english is poor.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/364451/play-rmvb-on-ubuntu-saucy-13-10

Answer (score 1):

***If VLC doesn't play it, nothing will play it!***  (It's probably a corrupt file)

If you could post the file itself somewhere, I could have a look at it with a hex editor, or if you would like you can do that yourself by:

```
sudo apt-get install ghex
ghex /path/to/file
```

and then comparing the first screen you see in ghex (the header of the file) to another `.rmvb` file.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)